# Why is print('a' > 'b') False and print('a' > 'A') True?

Tags: python-3.x, output, ascii

When we execute the program `print('a' > 'b')` it gives us the answer False.

When we execute the program `print('a' > 'A')` it gives us the answer True.

Please help me with a detailed explanation.

Comment: It might seem odd that 'a' is greater than 'A', but that's for historical reasons. The very early data encodings only supported upper case letters, lower case letters were added decades later. See (for example) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when comparing characters using the `<` or `>` it converts it to an integer.

according to [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

**Meaning:**

- a is 97 decimal
- b is 98 decimal
- A is 65 decimal
- B is 66 decimal

**therefor:**

`print('a' > 'b')` is false because `print(97 > 98)`

**and then:**

`print('a' > 'A')` is true because `print(97 > 65)`

Answer (score 2):

Please check the ascii code of the characters.

[image]

You can also check it using python

```py
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('b')
98
>>> ord('A')
65
```

Also, the reverse can be obtained as

```py
>>> chr(97)
'a'
>>> chr(98)
'b'
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, have a look at the [ASCII table](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) where you can find the numerical mapping of all the standard characters.

Did you see the **values of 'a', 'b', and 'A'**?

'a' == 97

'b' == 98

'A' == 65

That is why, *('a' > 'b') is false* and *('a' > 'A') is true*.

Answer (score 1):

This is because on the `ASCII (American Standard Code For Information Interchange) CHART` the letter "a" equates to 97 (in decimal values) while the letter "b" equates to 98 (in the decimal values).

Therefore when you type in `print('a' > 'b')`, Python compares the aforementioned decimal values and replies `"FALSE"` because under the hood is just comparing literally `97 to 98`. The same goes to `print('a' > 'A')`, it will be comparing `97 to 65`; reason why you will get a `"TRUE."`

Answer (score 0):

Computers can understand only numbers. So, every character has a numerical equivalent. Refer to more: https://www.asciitable.com/.
Decimal equivalent of
A=65, B=66, a=97, b=98

Clearly,
"A"<"B","B" <"C", "a"> "A"